# Is it possible to access the names of all build path jar files on which java project depends

Tags: java

The build path includes user libraries, tomcat libraries. Is it possible to return these jar names into a string list ?

Comment: Return where? Ant, Maven, ...?

Comment: Do you want to list in your application all the jars that have been loaded? I suppose it is a web app on Tomcat...

Comment: @Alin Stoian Its a web app running on websphere

Comment: @Tichodroma return this jar names into a string list, ive updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do the trick....

Source: http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2006/06/how-do-you-print-java-classpath.html

```
  public String getClasspathString() {
     StringBuffer classpath = new StringBuffer();
     ClassLoader applicationClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
     if (applicationClassLoader == null) {
         applicationClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
     }
     URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)applicationClassLoader).getURLs();
      for(int i=0; i < urls.length; i++) {
          classpath.append(urls[i].getFile()).append("\r\n");
      }    

      return classpath.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution looks robust enough to return all of the jars that a project depends on ? regardless if they are server jars, external jars, application jars ?

Comment: yes, this should return all the jar files regardless where they are coming from

Comment: I think this is a good solution, only slight issue I see is that the code must be run in same project as where project resides. Is it possible to run this from a separate project so as to inspect multiple projects ? I will accept this as answer regardless but is this amendment possible ?

Comment: I am afraid not... :(   I suppose when you say a different project you mean a different java process, in which case, you won't be able to get a hold of the class loader for that other process, so you won't be able to run this... But if this is for different projects deployed in a web server, you have to keep in mind that all of them share the same class loader, and so they share the same class path...

Answer (score 0):

You can also read this article:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

If you are interested also in the server jars, not only the application ones, you will have to list some additional directories:

common.loader : ${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar, ${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar

```
System.out.println(System.getProperties().getProperty("catalina.base", null));
System.out.println(System.getProperties().getProperty("catalina.home", null));
```